# Deployment of ASP.NET Core 2 to Azure is very slow

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core 2 app that I am working on to Azure.  Everything deploys, and it works in Azure, but it is incredibly slow to do so.  I mean like molasses in Canada in January slow.

I am using VS2017 and am selecting to publish the application from VS.  I have what I think is a fairly simple app, and it is taking 8-10 minutes to deploy in debug mode to an azure app service.

There seems to be a lot of build output regarding `ResolvedFileToPublish` that seems to go through the local set of assemblies/namespaces that are included in the application as well as nuget packages.

I've got another more complicated app built using some old tech that deploys to azure in under 2 minutes, so I am surprised by the amount of time for deploying a simple .NET Core 2 app.  Any suggestions/thoughts are appreciated.

TIA

Comment: FYI, I had some other projects in the same solution.  Somehow, this was the issue.  Creating a solution with just the asp.net core project resulted in the app compiling and deploying in the expected amount of time.